# attachmentClassifier - how to get zip version?

Tags: maven, zip, maven-assembly-plugin

Is it possible to get the zip version of some module (in this example case module:core-dll)
The zip is deployed to the repository:

http://repo01:8080/archiva/repository/snapshots/../core-dll/distribution/1.0-SNAPSHOT/core-dll-1.0-20111114.163405-1.zip

assembly.xml:

```
<moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
        <includes>
            <include>*:core-dll</include>
        </includes>
        <binaries>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
            <includeDependencies>false</includeDependencies>
            <attachmentClassifier>zip</attachmentClassifier>
            <outputDirectory>installation_files\plugins</outputDirectory>
        </binaries>
    </moduleSet>
</moduleSets>
```

Error I am getting:

```
Assembly: package is not configured correctly: 
Cannot find attachment with classifier: zip in module project: .. core-dll
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because `classifier` is not the same as packaging `type`.  The [pom](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html) reference gives the details, but suffice to say, the assembly plugin is expecting `core-dll-zip-<version>.jar` and not `core-dll-<version>.zip`

As for your requirement, not sure why you are using a `moduleSet`.  Perhaps you should consider using `dependencySet`. In this case, assuming the `dependency` is defined correctly (with the correct packaging `type`), I believe the assembly plugin will include it.  I haven't tried it though.

Comment: eventually i used dependencySet and not moduleSets and its working OK thank you for your help